# Can we bookmark/scroll to related list link in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience

In Classic Experience, we can bookmark related list url on any detail page. For example, If I am on account detail, as I click on any related list list shown on top of page layout, it produces a URL to scroll it at related list something like this: 
https://ayub-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00190000016ZNCt#00190000016ZNCt_RelatedCaseList_target

In lightning, I don't see such option- everything after hash are get removed when page loads in LEX. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a standard component for this purpose: [**Related List Quick Links**](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_related_list_quick_links_comp.htm), refer below:

[image]

Adding this to a page will look like something as below, the experience may not be exactly the same as in Classic because of the different UX as clicking on the links will take you actually to the object itself instead of staying on the detail page. And I will think that to be fine because consider how the page can be structured out in LEX -- say as tabs, all the way down after detail, single related list, on the right side of the page, etc. But this will serve your purpose as what you are looking for.

[image]